# Initial sessionId doesn't match final sessionId during logOut

Tags: node.js, express, axios, express-session

I created the session like this:

```
 async createSession(req, userId,moreData) {       
    try {
        const session = req.session;
        session.userId = userId;
        session.moreData = {
           ...moreData
        }
        session.save();
        console.log(`SessionId=${session.id}`); //I got 31ZCfRxGietdQLwVzi7c3KvgRh3mPCiq
    } catch (e) { }
}
```

Now for logOut,I have the following:

```
       req.session.destroy((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error destroying session:', err);
            } else {
                store.destroy(sessionId, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error destroying session in store:', err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`Destroyed ${sessionId}`); // I am getting oh_TDhyipSZ35PYDjd9SU-IS3MYYjm5K
                        res.redirect("/");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is my setup:

```
app.use(session({
        secret: SESSIONS_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { secure: true, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none' },
        store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: this.getSessionStoreURL() })
    }));
```

This is how I made the call on the frontend:

```
import axiosInstance from "axios";
  const axios = axiosInstance.create({
     withCredentials: true
  });
  static async logOut(cb) {
    axios.get(EndPoints.LOG_OUT, {
      headers: await this.getRequestHeaders(),
    }).then((response) => {
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Why are the session ids different?

Comment: Can you post the full logOut route? I am curious what store.destroy represents in the error handler for req.session.destroy. If you add a breakpoint before that and log out req.session.id, does it match?

Comment: @tris it's beyond just logOut. I just noticed that every request comes with a new sessionId. I'm very much confused why that is.

Comment: By virtue of the sessionStore and the withCredentials from axios I suppose things are supposed to work well, but that is currently not the case